# Getting react-hooks/exhaustive-deps error while trying to deploy a react app

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-hooks, use-effect, react-functional-component

I am trying to deploy a react app. The code/app works fine on my local end. However, when I am trying to deploy it, I am getting this error: 
`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'endGame'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Here is the code relevant to the error:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isTimeRunning && timeRemaining > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setTimeRemaining((time) => time - 1);
      }, 1000);
    } else if (timeRemaining === 0) {

      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
      return endGame();
    }
  }, [timeRemaining, isTimeRunning]);
```

I have tried several things, including adding endGame() function to an array(as second parameter on useEffect) but doing so brokes my app.
To see the whole code/project, please go to the repo, here: https://github.com/umbur/SpeedTypingGame

P.S. Please ask me further details, before marking this question as not relevant or something like that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be calling the function when adding it to the dependencies, but rather you should pass the function reference.

Try this: `[timeRemaining, isTimeRunning, endGame]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but doing so brokes the functionality of the app's timer. The endGame() function should be called when ```timeRemaining === 0```, that's why it needs to be in the ```else if``` condition

Comment: Adding `endGame` into the `useEffect` dependency array breaks your app?

Comment: Yes. However,  I've found the solution. Please see my answer, provided.

Answer (score 1):

So basically the issue was that I was not correctly applying(or ignoring `lint error`) this: `//eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` I should have applied it above the last line of that useEffect hook.
The correct way to fix those kind of issues is this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isTimeRunning && timeRemaining > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setTimeRemaining((time) => time - 1);
      }, 1000);
    } else if (timeRemaining === 0) {
      return endGame();
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [timeRemaining, isTimeRunning]);
```